# Case mismatch between class and real file names

Tags: php, symfony

I've just imported my project from my other pc, where it works perfectly. But now I test it here and I get the following error

"Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: BioscoopBundle\Entity\showschema vs BioscoopBundle\Entity\Showschema"

I searched around a bit and added this to my DebugClassLoader:

```
if ($name === $class) {
    if ($name !== $class && 0 === strcasecmp($name, $class)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(sprintf('Case mismatch between loaded and declared class names: %s vs %s', $class, $name));
    }
}
```

and now it gives me this:

"Case mismatch between class and real file names: BioscoopBundle\Entity\showschema.php vs BioscoopBundle\Entity\Showschema.php in C:\xampp\htdocs\debontekoe2\src\"

Note: I did change filenames on the other pc, I checked filenames and they are all corect but still give this error.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

thanks,

Comment: It randomly started working again.. Thanks anyway to everyone trying to help

Answer (score 0):

After clicking around in my project and going around the page giving the error for a bit. It randomly started working again. Thanks to everyone working on a solution for me. still puzzled why or how it happend but atleast it works.